# Extraction of correlation matrix, R, from BayesDCCgarch

Tags: r, finance, bayesian, coda

I am currently experimenting with the `bayesDCCgarch` package and have been looking to extract bivariate conditional correlations from the estimation of the model.

The output of the function only delivers the variance, covariance matrix **H_t**, which consists out of **H=DRD** (where D_t comes from the conditional variance estimate of the univariate garch model). I am looking for the **R** matrix

I have had a look in the code on the github [here](https://github.com/cran/bayesDccGarch/blob/master/src/bayesDccGarch.c) and have seen that in the script, `bayesDccGarch.c` they do calculate the correlation matrix **R** (lines 291 - 300)

```
// compute the R matrix
    for(i = 0; i < k; i++){
        hiit = omega[i];// /(1.0-beta[i]); // H_{ii,1}
        MEs[i][0]  = y[0][i]/sqrt(hiit);
        for(t = 1; t < n; t++){
            hiit = omega[i] + alpha[i]*y[t-1][i]*y[t-1][i] + beta[i]*hiit; // H_{ii,t}
            MEs[i][t]  = y[t][i]/sqrt(hiit); // Standard Errors
        }
    }   
    mcov(n, k, MEs, R); // compute the R matrix
```

Any help how I could plot correlation matrix **R** rather than the estimated volatilities for each of the series as in the code below:

```
 library(bayesDccGarch)
 data(DaxCacNik)  
 mY<-DaxCacNik[,1:2]
 out = bayesDccGarch(mY, nSim=1000)
 plotVol(mY, out$H[,c("H_1,1","H_2,2")], c("DAX","CAC40"))
```

I am looking to compare the correlation construction to that of the `dccfit` function in the `rmgarch` library.

Comment: Take a look at the output of `str(out)`. Could it be `out$control$cholCov`? I haven't used this function before, but maybe you'll be able to find it by exploring the elements of `out`.

Comment: Had a look at the object, could only see the MCMC, Information Criteria and the H matrix as the output object of the function (and control and time). I dont think a straight forward correlation construction such as `cov/sqrt(var)sqrt(var)` from the `out$H` matrix is the correct way to get the time-varying correlation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After haven spoken to the author of the package, the correct answer for the extraction of the correlation is indeed using the **H** matrix along with`cov/sqrt(var)sqrt(var)`:

```
 library(bayesDccGarch)
 data(DaxCacNik)  
 mY<-DaxCacNik[,1:2]
 out = bayesDccGarch(mY, nSim=10000)
 R<-out$H[,("H_2,1")]/sqrt(out$H[,("H_1,1")]*out$H[,("H_2,2")])
```